# Trying to compile R Package RSAP

Tags: r, package, saprfc

I'm trying to compile the R Package [RSAP](https://github.com/piersharding/RSAP) using the command

```
R CMD INSTALL RSAP
```

The necessary SAP library `SAP NW RFCSDK` is located in `C:\nwrfcsdk`.

- I'm building on Windows 10 64
- R version 3.4 32 bit (I tired 64 as well)
- R tools with mingw32

It does not compile but terminates with the following errors:

```
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc -shared -s -static-libgcc -o RSAP.dll tmp.def RSAP.o -L. -LC:/nwrfcsdk/lib -lsapnwrfc -llibsapucum -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib/i386 -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/bin/i386 -lR
RSAP.o:RSAP.c:(.text+0x4b): undefined reference to `RfcPing@8'
RSAP.o:RSAP.c:(.text+0x23a): undefined reference to `RfcUTF8ToSAPUC@24'
RSAP.o:RSAP.c:(.text+0x2d5): undefined reference to `RfcUTF8ToSAPUC@24'
RSAP.o:RSAP.c:(.text+0x369): undefined reference to `RfcUTF8ToSAPUC@24'
RSAP.o:RSAP.c:(.text+0x3ef): undefined reference to `RfcSAPUCToUTF8@24'
RSAP.o:RSAP.c:(.text+0x4b8): undefined reference to `RfcSAPUCToUTF8@24'
RSAP.o:RSAP.c:(.text+0x645): undefined reference to `RfcUTF8ToSAPUC@24'
RSAP.o:RSAP.c:(.text+0x6e3): undefined reference to `RfcUTF8ToSAPUC@24'
RSAP.o:RSAP.c:(.text+0x719): undefined reference to `RfcOpenConnection@12'
RSAP.o:RSAP.c:(.text+0x923): undefined reference to `RfcCloseConnection@8'
...
```

and so on until it stops with

> ```
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> keine DLL erzeugt
> ERROR: compilation failed for package 'RSAP'
> * removing 'C:/Users/jmueller/R/win-library/3.4/RSAP'
> * restoring previous 'C:/Users/jmueller/R/win-library/3.4/RSAP'
> ```

What am I doing wrong? Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: How about `install.packages('RSAP', repos=c('http://piersharding.com/R'), type="source", configure.args=c('--with-nwrfcsdk-include=C:/nwrfcsdk/include --with-nwrfcsdk-lib=C:/nwrfcsdk/lib'))
` as per installation instruction for windows?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I tried this and it also failed with the same error message. I thought it would be better to isolate the error using the standard tools. The include paths are exactly as specified in the build script of the package.

Comment: Have you told the compiler where SAP is located?

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens when you try to build RSAP in the 32-bit environment of R using the 64-bit version of the `SAP NW RFC SDK`. I had the same problem and after executing the following command in the 64-bit environment of RGui (with the 64-bit version of `SAP NW RFC SDK` located in `C:\nwrfcsdk`) the undefined references were gone.

**Command:**

```
install.packages('RSAP', repos=c('http://piersharding.com/R'), type="source", configure.args=c('--with-nwrfcsdk-include=C:/nwrfcsdk/include --with-nwrfcsdk-lib=C:/nwrfcsdk/lib'))
```

as described in:
https://github.com/piersharding/RSAP/blob/master/INSTALL